# Facebook ads insights api

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I need to pull all the interests in facebook ads insights [like](https://www.facebook.com/ads/audience_insights/).

Using graph api I can get particular user interests but I want all the interests that are in facebook.

Is there any api to get all the interests?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't extract the full interest database of Facebook. You should use the API per interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the api to the targeting options for a campaign and it returns all the nodes for interests.

The endpoint is:

```
graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/act_{ad-account-id}/targetingbrowse?limit_type=interests&acess_token={access_token}
```